# css ellipsis doesn't work: heading spawns on multiple lines

Tags: html, css

I want the heading(h4) in my page to truncate in one line using ellipse. So the h4 is inside a bootstrap span4 tag.

If the title doesn't fit on one line, I want it truncated. But in my case, the title spawns multiple lines even after adding the text-overflow:ellipsis tag. How do I make it stay on just one line and truncate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property in combination with `white-space: nowrap;` as well as the `overflow` property which must be something other than visible.
Try the following:

```
h4{
    width: 40px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```